# How can I stop a MySQL main table being SUMmed more than once when there is a sub-table SUM

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two MySQL tables: invoice and inv_pay
The invoice has a unique ID which links the payments ( inv_pay ) it also has a customer id
I want a list of all the customers with their total invoice value and their total amount paid
I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    CID Customer,SUM(i.InvNet) InvoiceValue, SUM(p.PayAmount) Paid
FROM
    invoice i
        LEFT JOIN
    inv_pay p ON p.InvID = i.InvID
GROUP BY i.CID
```

The problem is, when the customer pays with more than one instalment, the Invoice value is multiplied by the number of instalments.

I can't see how to use DISTINCT to make this work correctly

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO with some data (5-7 rows), desired output.

Comment: Read about the `over_clause` in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum). Then you wil no longer need DISTINCT.